# How to make an ArrayList that contains the x and y coordinates upon click?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, arraylist, jlist

What I want to do is store EVERY value of X and Y upon clicking an area of my image. How do I make that into an ArrayList? Also, There's a corresponding String in the JList for every turn of click.

For example, APPLES is selected in my JList, the click for X and Y is only for Apples. When I select another name, say CATS, it detects the point for CATS again, and saves it.

Basically, I just want to know how to store Objects in an arrayList, particularly the x and y coordinates of upon a mouse click. Thanks to anyone who can pitch in some ideas!

Comment: What language are you interested in?

Comment: Java :) oops sorry, I forgot to put it.

Comment: Users are asked to add a "homework" tag to questions related to homework.

Comment: @Michael This is not homework. It's a project. It's not something I should not take seriously. Plus, I'm merely trying to understand the Java language.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new `java.awt.Point` instance, which holds on to both the x and y coordinate in a single object, then store the Point instances into your list.

To track the clicks, register a `MouseListener`.  When clicked, the `mouseClicked` method of the MouseListener will be invoked, receiving a MouseEvent - which provides a `.getPoint` method that already returns a Point instance for you.

Comment: How do I do that? D: Sorry, I'm just a beginner in Java.

Comment: @alicedimarco: The instructions here are very clear... We're not here to do your homework for you. What do you not understand?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm very new to Java, especially GUI. How is the Point going to be "connected" to my label?